# How to edit the returned value of a function without changing the class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, pygame

I am designing a game and need to convert the script-variables from meters to pixels. My conversion factor is 30; 30 pixels to 1 meter. I have three levels of code:  my game engine, the game level, and my scripts.

The Game Engine creates a new game level "curmap" from the base class. Every frame in the game, the engine calls curmap.animate, which returns a list of where every object in the game gets blit'ed. The level iterates over every object within the level, and calls animate on each object.

**My Problem**

The issue I have is that in the Level-animate method, the player-animate method is returning direct references to the player-class-variables. The two commented lines in the Level-animate were meant to only alter the returned value, but instead they are modifying the player-variables. I can't reproduce this in a test class so I'm at a complete loss.

How do I uncomment those two inline multiplication statements without changing the player script?

The Game Engine:

```
# fps is an instance of pygame.time.clock()
# events is a modified list of pygame.event.get()

for item in curmap.animate(fps.tick()/1000, events):
    screen.blit(curmap.assets['textures'][item[0]],item[1],item[2])
```

The Level:

```
def animate(self, timedelta, events):
    returns = []
    for item in self.objects:
        ret = item.animate(timedelta, events)

        #ret[1][0] *= 30
        #ret[1][1] *= 30

        returns.append(ret)
    return returns
```

The Player Script:

```
def animate(self, timedelta, input):
    # Process Inputs
    for item in input['keydown']:
        self.keydown.append(item)
    for item in input['keyup']:
        self.keydown.remove(item)

    # Change Velocity and Position
    if "left" in self.keydown:
        self.velocity[0] = 5
    elif 'right' in self.keydown:
        self.velocity[0] = -5
    else: self.velocity[0] = 0
    print(self.position, self.velocity)
    self.position[0] += self.velocity[0]*timedelta
    self.position[1] += self.velocity[1]*timedelta


    # Change Sprite
    self.time += timedelta
    if self.time > self.altertime:
        self.current = (self.current+1)%2
        self.time -= self.altertime

    return [self.image, self.position, self.sprite[self.current] + self.dimensions]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what exactly `self.position` is in your `Player.animate` method, but if it's a simple list containing numeric values, just copy this list:

```
return [self.image, self.position[:], self.sprite[self.current] + self.dimensions]
```

---

You are returning the list `Player.position`, and when you alter it (you change the values inside the list) in `Level.animate`, you are actually changing `Player.position`, since you are working on *the same* list.

Comment: That works, thanks. Could you please explain _why_ I have to copy the list? In my test class I didn't need to do this, and in my previous experience this hasn't happened before.